# Trouble understanding how to maximize a specific vector's value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, optimization

I have recently modeled a small network and the interactions between its nodes with an equation. The data is stored in square matrices, $n \times n$ matrices. I only recently started looking into linear algebra and am still missing a lot of methods and theorems, so excuse me if the solution is very easy.

Here is said equation :

$a = (I_n - XD_H)^{-1}(XD_Hb + diag(XP_OO))$

With :

- $X$, $O$, $D_H$ and $D_O$ square, $n\times n$ matrices, with $D_O$ and $D_H$ being diagonal
- $a$ and $b$ vectors

**I would like to find what value of $X_{*;j}$, the $j^{th}$ column of $X$, maximizes $a_k$.**

I have gone with two different methods, that both lead me nowhere. Since I want to maximize $a_k$ with $X_{*;j}$, I decided to go with the following expression to work on : $e^T_k * a$, where $e^T_k$ is a vector of zeros, with only $(e^T_k)_k = 1$. I then differentiated this expression by $X_{*;j}$ or by $X_{i;j}$. My idea being to try solving $\frac{\partial e^T_k  a}{\partial X_{*;j}} = e^T_k \frac{\partial   a}{\partial X_{*;j}} = 0$.

However, everytime I got stuck and couldn't find the solution. I feel like differentiating $e^T_k  a$ is making things even more complicated, but I struggle to find a way to directly differentiate $a_k$. Any tips or advices to find the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you